# Подключение к серверу по порту

Tags: laravel, администрирование, сетевое-программирование

Здравствуйте у меня есть сервер. Подключаюсь по домену dom.com. Так же на этом сервере на 8080 порту сидит ларавел который требуется мне для апи. Все работает но с одним но.  При `http://dom.com:8080` запросе все работает но стоит мне поменять `http` на `https` ларавел не отвечает(Could not get any response). При переходе по адресу `https://dom.com` сайт работает без проблем. С SSL сертификатом все в порядке. Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Ну, из очевидного - подключить ssl к laravel?

Comment: Конфиги вэб-сервера в студию.